# Searching for a Laravel equivalent

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner webdeveloper.
I have small problem my model.

I have this migration and model:

```
Schema::create('stopwatches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('case_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('case_id')->references('id')->on('case_instances')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('timecycles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('timecycleable_id');
            $table->string('timecycleable_type');
            $table->integer('case_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('case_id')->references('id')->on('case_instances')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->integer('worked_time')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });


class Stopwatch extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'case_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'int',
        'case_id' => 'int',
        'user_id' => 'int',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function timeCycle()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Timecycle::class, 'timecycleable');
    }

    public function caseInstance()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CaseInstance::class, 'case_id');
    }




class Timecycle extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'case_id',
        'timecycleable_id',
        'timecycleable_type',
        'status',
        'worked_time'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'int',
        'case_id' => 'int',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function stopwatch()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

In timecycles I have 2 record with status = 0 and status = 1: https://ibb.co/5vyh316

I need my stopwatches with only one timecycles with status = 1.

I make this code:

```
return $this->stopwatch::with(['timeCycle', 'caseInstance'])
            ->where('user_id', Auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('updated_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(30)->toDateTimeString())
            ->whereHas('timeCycle', function ($q) {
                $q->where('status', 1);
            })
            ->get();
```

In result I have booth items: https://ibb.co/WnJ58Kc

What's wrong in my code?

How can I repair it?

Please help me.

Comment: Just to help you understand, the `whereHas` is a condition on the stopwatche, so only the stopwatches having the required timeCycle are loaded, then you're asking it to load the relation using `with` (without constraint) so it loads all the timeCycles of the filtered stopwatches

Answer (score 1):

You're actually quite close, but `whereHas()` doesn't affect the loaded records. Use the same clause on your `with()` statement:

```
return $this->stopwatch::with(['timeCycle' => function ($q) {
  $q->where('status', 1); // If you only want 1, you can do `->limit(1)` as well
}, 'caseInstance'])
->where('user_id', Auth()->user()->id)
->where('updated_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(30)->toDateTimeString())
->whereHas('timeCycle', function ($q) {
  $q->where('status', 1);
})
->get();
```

Now, when looping over your data, each `$record->timeCycle` will only include whatever is specified in the `with()` clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the problem is generated by the `with('timeCycle')` clause. If you want to constraint your query by a relation, you need to specified it in both the `whereHas` and the `with()`, otherwise the eager loading will fetch all the elements making the `whereHas` irrelevant. Try this:

```
return $this
    ->stopwatch::with([
        'caseInstance',
        'timeCycle' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
        }
    ])
    ->where('user_id', Auth()->user()->id)
    ->where('updated_at', '<=', now()->subSeconds(30)->toDateTimeString())
    ->whereHas('timeCycle', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Of course, given both constraints are equal, you could store it in a variable and pass it to both methods:

```
$timeCycleContraint = function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
};

return $this
    ->stopwatch::with([
        'caseInstance',
        'timeCycle' => $timeCycleContraint
    ])
    ->where('user_id', Auth()->user()->id)
    ->where('updated_at', '<=', now()->subSeconds(30)->toDateTimeString())
    ->whereHas('timeCycle', $timeCycleContraint)
    ->get();
```